# A and B gives or give? What should I use, singular or plural?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, singular-vs-plural

I want to express that fact A and fact B generate/produce/yield fact C.

However, I want to state that as "A, (together with B), [give/gives] C."

What should I use? Give or gives.

Comment: Apparently both are correct...."Mathematical texts tend to use the singular verb more often, and other written material seems to use the plural verb more often"  http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9053/should-i-use-the-singular-or-plural-verb-in-mathematical-formulae-two-and-two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question. To my ear, your second sentence should use the the third person singular conjugation(i.e. 'gives').

A grammatical justification would be that our subject is still only A, which by itself necessarily requires a third person singular conjugation. Your addition of "together with B" modifies A but does not change the subject, therefore, we must still use the conjugation 'gives'. Hope this helps!